# how to hide column in google charts table

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I've got a [Google Charts Table](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table.html) that displays a couple of columns and rows. Say for instance we have 4 columns(A,B,C,D respectively). How would I be able to still load column C's values, but just **hide** the column so that it's not getting displayed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of drawing the DataTable, you have to create an in-between DataView object where you filter the original data. Something like this:

```
//dataResponse is your Datatable with A,B,C,D columns        
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataResponse);
view.setColumns([0,1,3]); //here you set the columns you want to display

//Visualization Go draw!
visualizationPlot.draw(view, options);
```

The hideColumns method is maybe better instead of setColumns, choose yourself!

Cheers

Comment: is there a way to have this behavior happen when someone clicks on a link? For example, by default, I want to hide some columns (using view.hideColumns). Then I want to have an 'Expand' link above the table that when the user clicks on it, the remaining columns are exposed (using view.setColumns). I'm also open to suggestions for better implementations of this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative using a ChartWrapper instead of a chart.

```
var opts = {
    "containerId": "chart_div",
    "dataTable": datatable,
    "chartType": "Table",
    "options": {"title": "Now you see the columns, now you don't!"}
}
var chartwrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(opts);

// set the columns to show
chartwrapper.setView({'columns': [0, 1, 4, 5]});    
chartwrapper.draw();
```

If you use a ChartWrapper, you can easily add a function to change the hidden columns, or show all the columns.  To show all the columns, pass `null` as the value of `'columns'`.  For instance, using jQuery,

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // use your preferred method to get an array of column indexes or null
    var columns = eval($(this).val());

    chartwrapper.setView({'columns': columns});    
    chartwrapper.draw();
});
```

In your html,

```
<button value="[0, 1, 3]" >Hide columns</button>
<button value="null">Expand All</button>
```

(Note:  `eval` used for conciseness.  Use what suits your code.  It's beside the point.)

Answer (score 2):

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(dataTable); //datatable contains col and rows
view.setColumns([0,1,3,4]); //only show these column
chart.draw(view, options); //pass the view to draw chat
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS.

"#table_div" is the div my table is wrapped in. I use this because there a multiple tables on the same page.

```
#table_div .google-visualization-table table.google-visualization-table-table 
   td:nth-child(1),th:nth-child(1){
   display:none;
}
```

I also have an event handler on the chart's rows, and can still pick up the data from the hidden column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use particular column value in control wrapper but don't want to show that column in Google Charts then do following things.

1) Add all column to your google charts data table.
2) Add following things to **options** of your chartWrapper.

```
   // Set chart options
    optionsUser = {
        "series": {
            0: {
                color: "white",
                visibleInLegend: false
            }
        }
    };
```

3) In above code series, 0 means the first line in your line chart. So It will set the color to white and also hide column name in Legends.

4) This way is not the proper way to hide columns, Using DataView is recommended. Whenever you want to use data in the data table for adding controls to your chart but don't want to show that column in the chart this is the way.